# Using .NET 4.0 Task in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, .net-4.0, task

Are there any caveats or short comings to using the new Task API in `System.Threading.Task` in ASP.NET hosted under IIS?

I know prior to .NET 4.0 working with any of the ThreadPool actions inside of IIS was always recommended to be avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any caveats to using ThreadPool with IIS would still be valid using `System.Threading.Task`, as the Task API is just an additional layer of abstraction over `System.Threading`.

For long-running tasks in the background, I use a `ThreadPool` inside a Windows Service.  This keeps it outside of IIS.

Comment: This was pretty much what I was looking for whether Task was a new and different construct or just an abstraction on top of ThreadPool.