# Threads not starting in ASP.Net on server but works fine locally

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, iis, iis-7.5

I have been working on my first use of threading in an ASP.Net application and encountered a problem.

The code works fine when I run it locally, yet as soon as I have uploaded to our dev server it doesnt run, but also doesnt error.

I did some research and found that I should have the thread impersonate the WindowsIdentity, which I have done but still the thread does not work, I also tried increasing the max threads in IIS and still nothing.

Im assuming the issue is with IIS as this is the only thing that is different between my local machine and the server but I have no experience in IIS and am completely stuck on this so any help would be appreciated.

Im running IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2.

The method being executed on a new thread is in a class in the App_Code folder and looks like:

```
Public Class RosterEmailer
      Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

      Dim thisID As String
      Dim thisName As String
      Dim strDutyStartDate As date
      Dim thisWorkEmail As String
      Dim thisHomeEmail As String
      Dim mailbody As string
   Dim Sec As Object 

   Public sub Ini(ByVal _thisID As String, 
                       ByVal _thisName As String, 
                       ByVal _strDutyStartDate As date,
                       ByVal _thisWorkEmail As String,
                       ByVal _thisHomeEmail As String,
                       ByVal _mailbody As string,
                       ByVal _security As Object)

      thisID = _thisID 
      thisName = _thisName 
      strDutyStartDate = _strDutyStartDate 
      thisWorkEmail = _thisWorkEmail 
      thisHomeEmail = _thisHomeEmail 
      mailbody = _mailbody 
      Sec = _security 

   End Sub

   Public Sub SendMail()

    Dim id as  System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity  = CType(Sec,System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)
      id.Impersonate()
               'Dim response As System.Web.HttpResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response

               'Declare the SMTP server we are going to use 
               Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("192.168.20.11")
               Dim cred As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("domain\\username","mypassword")
               smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
               smtp.Credentials = cred

               Dim mail As New MailMessage()

               ' create email
               mail.From = New MailAddress("rostering@ourdomain.com")
               mail.To.Add(thisWorkEmail)
               mail.CC.Add(thisHomeEmail)

               mail.Subject = thisName + " Roster from our company for " + strDutyStartDate.Month.ToString() + "_" + strDutyStartDate.Year.ToString()

               mail.IsBodyHtml = True

               mail.Priority = MailPriority.High

               mail.Body = mailbody

               Dim strURL As String = "http://blueprintdev/Opsproject/Ops/rosteroutput.aspx?InstructorID=" & thisID.ToString() & "&Instructor=" & thisName.ToString() & "&Start=" & strDutyStartDate

               Dim holder As String = String.Empty 

               Dim uu As New Uri(strURL,UriKind.Absolute)
               Dim rq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uu)
               Dim res As HttpWebResponse = rq.GetResponse() 
               Dim stream1 As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()

               Using r1 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream1,Encoding.UTF8)
                  holder = r1.ReadToEnd()
               End Using

               Dim pdfConverter As PdfConverter = New PdfConverter
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = PDFPageOrientation.Landscape
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfCompressionLevel = PdfCompressionLevel.Normal
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowHeader = True
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowFooter = True
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.LeftMargin = 5
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.RightMargin = 5
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.TopMargin = 5
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.BottomMargin = 5
               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.GenerateSelectablePdf = True

               pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowHeader = False
               pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterText = ("Printed on " & Now())
               pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterTextColor = Color.DarkBlue
               pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterTextFontSize = "10"

               pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterTextFontType = PdfFontType.Helvetica
               pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.DrawFooterLine = True
               pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.PageNumberText = "Page"
               pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.PageNumberTextFontType = PdfFontType.Helvetica
               pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.PageNumberTextFontSize = "10"
               pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.ShowPageNumber = True
               pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "theKeyGoesHere"

               Dim downloadBytes() As Byte = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString("<font face='verdana' size='1'>" & holder)

               Dim stream As Stream = New MemoryStream(downloadBytes)

               Dim filename As String = thisName + "_Roster_" + strDutyStartDate.Month.ToString() + "_" + strDutyStartDate.Year.ToString() + ".pdf"

               ' add pdf to email
               Dim att As Attachment = New Attachment(stream, filename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf.ToString())

               mail.Attachments.Add(att)
               ' send email
               smtp.Send(mail)
   End Sub
End Class
```

I then call this from a method in my codebehind like:

```
Dim sec As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

       Dim emailer As RosterEmailer = New RosterEmailer()
       emailer.Ini(thisID,thisName,strDutyStartDate,thisWorkEmail,thisHomeEmail,body,sec) 

       Dim Thr As System.Threading.Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf emailer.SendMail))

       Thr.Start()
```

Comment: An ASP.NET web application is the wrong place to get familiar with threading, not least because you should never, ever, _really need_ to do this, and otherwise, but not limited to, it being the 'wrong' environment. See [here also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5553048/263681)

Comment: Im using threading here because I need to send about 150 emails, they each have a PDF which is generated and added then the email is sent, without threading this takes about 5 minutes and times out the browser, with threading it takes about 28 seconds

Comment: That's just an excuse for not breaking up the project into its proper parts. Use threading, just not _here_.

Comment: How would you suggest I accomplish this if threading shouldnt be used here?

Comment: Did you read the link I posted?

Comment: Cheers, didnt see the edit. going to have a read now

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with the recommendations here. More specifically, I would set up a queue of these emails (and their constituent components) that need to be sent out on the web app side. This allows it to perform quick write to the DB and be done.

The second piece is to use a mechanism to check the queue (table in aforementioned DB) and process the outbound emails. Simple options include a window-less console-style app that performs this when executed by the Task Schedule in Windows, a Windows service that wakes up every few minutes to check the queue and so on, and more.

Since a Windows service feels a bit heavy for what you are doing and due to speed-to-prototype for a console app, I would recommend you go the console app direction. This also allows you to very easily test run times and performance on development, test, and production environments with less overhead in environmental migration planning.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the WindowsIndentity you pass into the thread function. On ASP.NET in a web application the security context is released after the request thread is finished. This in practice means that the WindowsIdentity passed in the background/long running thread becomes unoperational (for example accessing the Name property would cause an error).

If the email sender thread requires that it runs in the security scope of the requesting user (for delegation, etc purposes) you have to wrap your code in a service published with WCF. The WCF IIS host pertains security context on forked threads. (To my experience this is also the case with Visual Studio Web Dev server)

On the other hand if you are just to use the properties of the WindowsIndentity than simply collect them in the request thread and pass this collection to the background thread instead.