# spin the task up in a separate process outside of IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, parallel-processing

In this answer
[How should I perform a long-running task in ASP.NET 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553001/how-should-i-perform-a-long-running-task-in-asp-net-4/5553068#5553068) they recommend spinning the task up in a separate process outside of IIS. Is this possible?

So in my asp.net application can I pass off some task to a different process? Not a thread but a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely possible.

Think Windows Service.  Think MSMQ.  Think CreateProcess(...).

Comment: Would you be able to give a small example?

Comment: I guess I'm translating "spinning the task up in separate process" as just making a call from within asp.net. If I was thinking windows service. Would that service have to be installed and running? So I'm not just making a call like in a threading but instead I'm putting all the other infrastructure in place before hand.

Comment: Yes I'm looking at CreateProcess() but I would have to pass it an exe file. I can't just give it existing code in my asp.net application like I can do with thread. Am I even thinking this correctly?

Comment: You should not be running long-running tasks within the IIS/ASPNET process - threaded or not.  Pass it off to CreateProcess  (i.e. Process.Start(...) ).

Comment: Yes I agree it shouldn't be within IIS process. I guess my question is how can I spin off a new process without having the actual executable sitting on the server. In other words just calling a block of code. I think the answer is I can't do that and I have to invest in setting up the process/executable or windows service.

Comment: you could try using MSMQ.  That will work across machine boundaries.  Still need some code (application or service) to process the queue.