# Should I have a keep alive process in IIS application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In my web app on start up I have a number of threads that are currently running and do all sorts of work (such as releasing database locks, monitoring users etc). These threads are started on the application_start() event in my asp.net app.

What concerns me is if the app pool dies for some reason, these threads will not start up again until a request is made to the application (i.e. app domain loaded etc).

I was thinking about scheduling a batch process (via command line and vb-script) every 10 mins to make a web request which will ensure that my application is already loaded and running (threads will be up then).

So far I have not seen any problems with the app pool crashing so it was a precautionary measure.

I noticed my app pool currently has a default setting of 20 mins to recycle.

I was wondering if this approach is correct and I do not introduce any other problems down the road.

We are using IIS 6 so cannot use the Application warm up module which I suppose is not for app pools crashing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I perform a long-running task in ASP.NET 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553001/how-should-i-perform-a-long-running-task-in-asp-net-4). Regardless of the .NET/ASP.NET version my answer there stands for websites in IIS. That is, create a Windows Service to do the stuff.