# Frequently refreshing web page during long-running process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I've been hunting around my issue for a while, probably the best I've come up with is another Stack Overflow question: [How should I perform a long-running task in ASP.NET 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553001/how-should-i-perform-a-long-running-task-in-asp-net-4)

I'm in a similar place in that I'm wanting to understand what my options are, but I don't feel I know enough specifically about MVC to come to a view. I'm using MVC 5 but with the 4.8 framework, plus I note that technologies such as SignalR have become available since this question was asked. I was wondering if any experienced MVC'ers could give me a view?

I too have a long running process. More specifically, the user is importing a file. The file is delimited so the import happens line by line. The file might be thousands of lines long. Each line will be parsed and imported in a fraction of a second but the whole operation might take several minutes.

I don't particularly need behaviour to be asynchronous, but because of the length of the entire process I want to regularly update the user on progress. I'm wondering what options I have?

I've got a vague recollection that I might have looked at this problem 20-odd years ago (Classic ASP), and solved it by regular flushes, sending a bit more of the page to the client every few seconds, but I'm trying also to use a _Layout page now, so I've sent the page back already. So I don't think I have that option, even assuming such a mechanism still exists. A bit more recently, but still a while ago, I might have used javascript to poll but everything I'm reading now seems to point me to newer technologies which I'm not sure I fully understand yet.

I'm just wondering how would *you* solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not be performing any of the file parsing on the web server, especially if it's thousands of rows long.  I would delegate this to a background service of sorts, whether that be a Lambda service in the cloud or a Windows service or a scheduled task.  You could then call your SignalR hub from the background task (whatever that might be) to update the progress of the import.

Comment: Thanks. that makes perfect sense, but I'm now thinking carefully about how the UI gets updated. If I have a discrete (something) to perform the import, there's no reason it has to have any association with a web site at all, so the (something) should probably steer clear of using e.g. SignalR. A year ago I was writing this whole application with a WPF client, more my comfort zone, but I'd like to think of a way to retrofit if I ever go back to it.

Comment: You don't have to bind the CSV parsing service to a SignalR implementation.  You could specify a callback URL when you generate the request which the CSV parsing service would call when it completes.  That way it's completely agnostic.